# Complex vector bundle that does not admit holomorphic structure

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Is there any example of a complex vector bundle $E \to M$ whose base space $M$ is also a complex manifold, but where the total space $E$ does not admit a holomorphic structure compatible with the bundle structure?

Of course, I have already run into [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/7304/1871) before. But I am not specifically interested in the case where the base is a Fano or even an algebraic variety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex line bundles over $X$ are clssified by $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. Hence choose some cohomology class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ but not in $H^{1,1}(X)$ will give you an example.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any condition on a (compact?) complex manifold $X$ that guarantees the existence of a $2$-dimensional integral cohomology class that is not in $H^{1,1}(X)$? (For example, taking $X  =\mathbb P^n$ would not work, I think.)

Comment: @pyon Here's an example in my mind. Let $E_{1}, E_{2}$ be two elliptic curve and $C_{1}, C_{2}$ be two cycle on them. Then $C_{1}*C_{2}\subset E_{1}*E_{2}$ is an example

Comment: Ah, I see, many thanks again! (You probably wanted to use `\times` instead of `*` in your LaTeX code, btw.)

Comment: @pyon Yeah. It's a bit wired that I can't edit my comment now and have to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, I have to give an answer here: Take any smooth vector bundle $\mathcal{E} \to X$ over a complex manifold $X$. The complexification $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathbf{C}$ is a complex vector bundle. In general, this is far from a holomorphic vector bundle, however.

Comment: Thanks! While it is true that the complexification $\mathcal E \otimes \mathbb C$ does not have a *canonical* holomorphic structure, how do you know that it will not be compatible with *any* holomorphic structure whatsoever?

Comment: @pyon Your question is a good one. Have you taken a look at this mathoverflow post -- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8484/reps-of-un-for-the-bundles-of-holomorphic-and-antiholomorphic-forms-of-proje ? Specifically, David E Speyer's answer?

Comment: I have not, but I will look at it. Thanks again!